# Configure VisualVM to visualize multiple JVMs

Tags: jvm, visualvm

I would like to use VisualVM to monitor a cluster of JVMs, say 50 - 100 processes.

Is there a way to configure VisualVM to monitor to a specified list of JVMs on startup without adding them manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can run [jstatd](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html) on each of the machines, and then you will need just to connect to the machines - all processes will be added automatically.